# Can I use both onclick events and submit functionality on a form's submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am confused about some behaviour on my webpage where I use both submit action and onclick event on the Save-button in a form. It works fine for me, but it seems that some users have trouble to save the information in the form.

I have simplified the form here:

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="myform" action="action.php">
        <input "nameinput" type="text" name="name">
        <button id="savebutton" type="submit" >Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now... I have also added an jQuery section that shall hide the form when the save button is pressed:

```
$(".container").on("click", "#savebutton", function(){        
    $("#myform").slideUp("slow", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

So: When the user presses the Save-button it shall both send the `name` to `action.php` and trigger the click-event to close the form.

This works perfectly fine for me, but I wonder if this design can cause troubles on some browsers, especially older ones? I have got bug reports from users where the form is closed, but no data is saved (i.e. `action.php` isn't called). Is it possible that the form "dissapears" before the form can submit the data?

Comment: Instead of hiding put a loader there and then check is data insertion was success. then hide the form

Comment: @NipunTharuksha... Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Are you validating the data insertion. Means if someone enter a name and click the button do you check is that entry was inserted before hide the form

Answer (score 0):

Here the default behavior of the submit button is to send the data to action.php. Definitely, it is going to load the page again when users click the submit button in that case your javascript code will not run.

I will recommend you to use JQUERY AJAX [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)